# Import error, there is no module named numpy, but it says that it is installed?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, cntk

So I trying to install and run from MSFT the cntk, you know, just for fun. Anyway, I keep getting this error which says:

```
import numpy as np
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Now I have looked around here a little and I found a post saying that I needed to install the latest version of NumPy, but when I go to do that, I get back this:

Requirement already satisfied: NumPy in c:\users\username\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\envs\cntk-py34\lib\site-packages

SO I really have no idea what is going on here.

Anyway, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is your IDE linked to Anaconda env? If you open up the Anaconda prompt and import numpy do you get the same error?

You probably have an environment outside of Anaconda which does not have numpy installed.

Comment: Sorry, I am brand new to python. No I was using the cmd promt, not the Anaconda one. Can I just ask, where can I find the Anaconda prompt?

Comment: Warning, I do not use windows often. But there should be a Anaconda Prompt in your start menu. You could also try starting spyder by running spyder in a prompt.

Comment: Ah I see spyder. Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to import in spyder?

Comment: I figured out what was going on. I was using visual studio, and I needed to right click on the Python Environments and select which ones I needed to use. Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: Anytime! Let me know if you have any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was executing `[filename].py` from the Anaconda prompt as I would a batch file and was getting this error. I confirmed numpy was install by executing `pip list`.

Funning `python` and passing the script file name as an argument, eg `python [filename].py`, correctly imported the numpy module and executed the script without error.